# Click after preventDefault not doing the default

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a situation where I need to stop a click on an a tag based on some async stuff.  This is inside an Angular Js directive that is attached to a tags, but I don’t think it is relevant.

```
—-getting the elem
$elem.bind(‘click’, (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
-- do the async stuff
—- assume continue case
$elem.unbind(event) —- do not want this handler to execute again
$elem.click();
}
```

Now the other handlers attached to the element are executed, but the default behavior of navigating to the href is not happening.  What have I done wrong or omitted?

Comment: I would take a closer look at the argument expected by `unbind`.

Comment: Looks like the last line calls the whole function itself and preventDefault gets called.. what exactly should happen after the async part?

Comment: According to the jQ docs that unbind is how it is done inside the handler itself.  The click does not call itself because of the unbind.  The async stuff just determines if the other handlers or default behavior should execute

Comment: Try getting the actual DOM element and calling click on it.

Comment: This does not seem like the angular way to do things. If you are trying to stop the click handler from being called again, do a check for some variable, either in scope (if you need to change something in the template) or outside of it in the directive link function. No need to unbind.